# Ubuntu 20.04 lags when extensions using GLib spawn command with pgrep

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell-extension

When I was on 19.10 with GNOME 3.34 I could spawn command with GLib so many times without causing any lag to the GNOME shell or any app. But on 20.04 with GNOME 3.36.1 even a simple spawn command can create some lags for entire GNOME shell and even apps.

To show you how I do it, I've created this simple GNOME shell extension:

```
const Mainloop = imports.mainloop;
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;

let timeout;

function init(){
}

function enable(){
    timeout = Mainloop.timeout_add_seconds(1.0,() => {
      var [ok, out, err, exit] = GLib.spawn_command_line_sync('pgrep Discord');
      log('Discord is running');
      return true;
    });
}

function disable(){
    Mainloop.source_remove(timeout);
}
```

Why is that lag happening? how can I fix the lag issue on this code?

Comment: Could somebody please add the tag pgrep (and maybe procps) because this is the culprit?

Comment: @Sven Added pgrep to the title. pgrep cannot be added as tag.

Answer (score 2):

`pgrep` in Ubuntu 20.04 is extremely slow. The run time is linear to your stack limit (`ulimit -S -s` to check), it can easily reach 30 sec even on fast machines. If you have no stack limit, any `pgrep` call will fail:

```
cannot allocate 4611686018427387903 bytes
```

Bug reports are open for Ubuntu (Debian, Archlinux), but see no traffic. Please consider marking that you are affected too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/1874824

The bug is fixed in procps, but distributions are not picking it up ...

Comment: We didn't have this problem in 19.04. It was very fast before 20.04.